# Poetry fails to install Scipy (Manjaro Linux, Python 3.10.5)

Tags: python, pip, scipy

I'm trying to install Scipy using Poetry, but I get the following error message:

```
Using version ^1.9.0 for scipy

  The current project's Python requirement (>=3.10,<4.0) is not compatible with some of the required packages Python requirement:
    - scipy requires Python >=3.8,<3.12, so it will not be satisfied for Python >=3.12,<4.0
  
  Because scipy (1.9.0) requires Python >=3.8,<3.12
   and no versions of scipy match >1.9.0,<2.0.0, scipy is forbidden.
  So, because assistant depends on scipy (^1.9.0), version solving failed.

  at ~/.local/share/pypoetry/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/poetry/puzzle/solver.py:241 in _solve
      237│             packages = result.packages
      238│         except OverrideNeeded as e:
      239│             return self.solve_in_compatibility_mode(e.overrides, use_latest=use_latest)
      240│         except SolveFailure as e:
    → 241│             raise SolverProblemError(e)
```

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar dependency error with poetry failing to install scipy.  The fix for me was to change the line for Python in my `pyproject.toml` file from:

```
python = "^3.10"
```

to

```
python = ">=3.10,<3.12"
```

I'm not entirely sure why this fixed it, because it hasn't actually changed the version of python it installed, just how it thinks about the constraints.

**EDIT 16/05/2023**
This is because `^3.10` implies version `>=3.10,<4.0` while `scipy` explicitly supports python up to version `3.12`